# Excel vba run time error 438 (If Cl.Value Like str And Rng2.Cl.Value <> "" Then)

Tags: vba

I have a code to copy data from one sheet to another using if and vlookup function but not working

```
Sub CopyRows()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Cl As Range
Dim str As String
Dim RowUpdCrnt As Long

Set UsedRange = Sheets("Jan").Range("b5:Am81")
Set Rng = Sheets("Jan").UsedRange  'the range to search ie the used range
Set Rng2 = Sheets("Feb").Range("I5:AK5")
str = "WRK." 'string to look for
Sheets("Feb").Range("B5:B81").Value = ""

RowUpdCrnt = 5

' In my test data, the "WRK."s are in column AN.  This For-Each only selects column AN.
' I assume all my "WRK."s are in a single column.  Replace "B" by the appropriate
' column letter for your data.

With Sheets("Jan")
' loop until last row with data in Column AN (and not the entire column) to save time
  For Each Cl In .Range("AN1:AN" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AN").End(xlUp).Row)
    If Cl.Value Like str And Rng2.Cl.Value <> "" Then
    'if the cell contains the correct value copy it to next empty row on sheet 2 &  delete the row
      If Not IsError(Application.Vlookup(.Range("B" & Cl.Row).Value, Sheets("Master").Range("H7:H200"), 1, 0)) Then   ' <-- verify the VLookup was successful
        Sheets("Feb").Range("B" & RowUpdCrnt).Value = Application.Vlookup(.Range("B" & Cl.Row).Value, Sheets("Master").Range("H7:H200"), 1, 0)
        RowUpdCrnt = RowUpdCrnt + 1       
      End If
    End If  
  Next Cl
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: This here does not work: `Rng2.Cl.Value`. `Cl` is a range (cell) in Sheets('Jan'). You cannot access that range variable on a different sheet like that. I take it you want to access the same cell address there? Try `If Cl.Value Like str And Rng2.Range(Cl.Address).Value <> "" Then` instead.

Comment: Another thing: using `Like`without a wildcard works just like comparing to `Equals`. Better would be (guessing here as to where the wildcard belongs): `str = "WRK.*"`

Answer (score 1):

I just went over this once more.
You made several errors in this one:

1. UsedRange:

   `Set UsedRange = Sheets("Jan").Range("b5:Am81")`

   `Set Rng = Sheets("Jan").UsedRange`

This does not what I think you think it would. Also given how you address ranges later on, you don't need these anyway.

2. `Set Rng2 = Sheets("Feb").Range("I5:AK5")`

As you don't do anything with that specific range, it is not needed either.

3. `Rng2.Cl.Value` is an invalid construct and `Like "WRK."` has no wildcard as mentioned in my comment.

Based on this I have stripped your code of these unneccessaries and corrected where errors were directly visible:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRows()

Dim Cl As Range
Dim str As String
Dim RowUpdCrnt As Long

str = "WRK.*" 'string to look for
Sheets("Feb").Range("B5:B81").Value = ""

RowUpdCrnt = 5

' In my test data, the "WRK."s are in column AN.  This For-Each only selects column AN.
' I assume all my "WRK."s are in a single column.  Replace "B" by the appropriate
' column letter for your data.

With Sheets("Jan")
' loop until last row with data in Column AN (and not the entire column) to save time
  For Each Cl In .Range("AN1:AN" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AN").End(xlUp).Row)
    If Cl.Value Like str And Sheets("Feb").Range(Cl.Address).Value <> "" Then
    'if the cell contains the correct value copy it to next empty row on sheet 2 &  delete the row
      If Not IsError(Application.Vlookup(.Range("B" & Cl.Row).Value, Sheets("Master").Range("H7:H200"), 1, 0)) Then   ' <-- verify the VLookup was successful
        Sheets("Feb").Range("B" & RowUpdCrnt).Value = Application.Vlookup(.Range("B" & Cl.Row).Value, Sheets("Master").Range("H7:H200"), 1, 0)
        RowUpdCrnt = RowUpdCrnt + 1       
      End If
    End If  
  Next Cl
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

No guarantees given since I currently don't have the time to re-create a fake of your data to try and test this. Should work though.

Comment: Yep. `UsedRange` is an undefined local variable here. OP needs to start using `Option Explicit`!

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of undeclared locals; given your code apparently *runs*, I presume `Option Explicit` isn't specified.

This makes local variable `Rng2` be declared on-the-spot at runtime as a `Variant/Range`. That's great, except that, well, at design-time, you don't get *IntelliSense* to ensure you're writing code that.. well, makes sense. Like this:

> ```
> Rng2.Cl.Value
> ```

`Cl` is a local `Range` object variable, but you're using it as if it were a member of `Rng2` - *because* you're not declaring `Rng2`, VBA happily compiles the code and, instead of complaining at compile-time, blows up at run-time with error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method". In other words, `Range.Cl` does not exist, and VBA doesn't know what to do with it - as the current build (v2.0.12, scheduled for release early February) of [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduckvba.com/) (an open-source VBE add-in I'm heavily involved with) could have told you:

[image: Member 'Cl' is not declared on the interface for type 'Range'.]

So instead of this:

> ```
> If Cl.Value Like str And Rng2.Cl.Value <> "" Then
> ```

You could try [LocEngineer's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41809266/excel-vba-run-time-error-438-if-cl-value-like-str-and-rng2-cl-value-then#comment70806923_41809266), depending on exactly what you're trying to do:

```
 If Cl.Value Like str And Rng2.Range(Cl.Address).Value <> "" Then
```